# Finding basis for image of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have been looking up how to find the basis of an image online.

I found a solution on StackExchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895406/how-to-find-a-basis-of-an-image-of-a-linear-transformation)

It seems that to find the basis we reduce the rows to row echelon form.

Then we find the rows with leading values and use their corresponding vectors from the non-reduced matrix as linearly independent vectors for the basis.

My question is this:

If we perform operations on the rows of the matrix (i.e - swapping the rows), and we finally reduce it fully. Then we go back to the rows of the original matrix, corresponding to the rows with leading values in the reduced matrix, couldn't we be picking the wrong vectors. Since we swapped the rows do we have to keep track of where we swapped them?

If not, why not?

Specifically given the example in the link, it's clear the row $(1, -2 ,1)$ was swapped to the top. Hence, when we are finding the corresponding rows after the reduction, must we take into account this swap.

Sorry if my question is phrased badly or if it confuses anyone.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The key thing to notice is that a basis for the image is given by the columns (and not the rows) of the original matrix corresponding to the leading 1's in any row echelon form.  This set gives a maximal linearly independent set of columns, so it forms a basis for the column space.

Comment: In the link, it looks to me like he used the rows as the basis. Am I wrong here? Sorry for sounding a bit ignorant, could you explain in the simplest terms possible. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the first answer to this question (which apparently was written by me), you can see that the columns were used.  The key ideas are that the image of a linear transformation corresponds to the column space of its standard matrix, and a basis for the column space is given by the columns corresponding to the columns in any REF which have leading ones.