# Find Image of a matrix - difference between two different methods

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been searching about how to find image of a matrix. Particularly, I have seen two different methods to accomplish. As a result, I have tried both methods on the same question. Since they result in two different answers, I don't know which one should be correct

Suppose we are asked to find the image of the following matrix:

$$\displaystyle A =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

**Method 1:** (Learned from: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242282/706640 )

We calculate the RREF of $A^T$. We have following:
$$\displaystyle RREF(A^T) =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{5}{3} & 1 \\0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} &0 \\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then we take each non-zero rows and transform into column form, then we have the image:

$$\displaystyle Im(A) = span \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{5}{3} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -\frac{1}{3} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

**Method 2** (From: [How to find a basis of an image of a linear transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895406/how-to-find-a-basis-of-an-image-of-a-linear-transformation))

We calculate simply RREF of A:
$$\displaystyle RREF(A) =\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&-2\\0&1&1\\0&0&0 \\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

We have pivots in the first and second column, we extract these two columns from the original matrix, and we obtain the image.
$$\displaystyle Im(A) = span \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\-1\\2\\1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3\\0\\5\\3 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

So as we can see, we have two different answers *(Or are they?)*. As a result, I am not sure which is the right way to do especially both methods seems to be correct. What is the difference?

I used online tool to calculate the RREF of each matrix, so I assume there isn't any numerical error

Comment: Without looking at the numerical details either approach seems OK to me. It seems to be an outcome of the fact that the usual algorithm for computing a basis for the row space of a matrix generally produces different vectors from the rows of the matrix, while the usual algorithm for computing a basis for the column space of a matrix explicitly identifies columns of the original matrix that span the column space. And transposing of course turns columns into rows.

Comment: But are they the same? I mean are they considered to be different image of the matrix? Suppose they are the same, but I don't see why

Comment: They're different lists of vectors. And I have not performed the computation myself. But generally different methods of computing a basis may produce different results. That is fine because vector spaces generally have large numbers of bases. I note that one vector in one computation appears to be a scalar multiple of a vector in the other computation. So to nail this down would essentially reduce to testing whether the second vector (in each basis) can be expressed as a linear combination of the two vectors in the other basis. If you've done the calculations right, you'll see that it can.